# Is there any API available to access Notice of Change Reports?

Tags: authorize.net

When we login to merchant account on authorize.net website, we can see a report titled "eCheck.Net ® Notice of Change Reports" under Reports menu. Is there any API available to access this report programatically? I'm already using Auth.NET API from C# code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no API provided by Authorize.Net to retrieve this data that I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Talked with support team they confirmed there's no such API available as of now.